# Perform multiple actions in same time

Tags: c#, task, multitasking

I want to perform multiple loops in the same time using async Task (I don't want use `Parallel.ForEach`)

I do :

```
static async void Run()
{
    await MultiTasks();
}

static async Task MultiTasks()
{
    var Loop1 = Loop1Async();
    var Loop2 = Loop2Async();

    await Loop1;
    await Loop2;
}

static async Task Loop1Async()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Loop 1 : " + i);
    }
}

static async Task Loop2Async()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Loop 2 : " + i);
    }
}
```

`Run()` is called in my Main method.

But the two loop is not executed in the same time. Once the first lap is completed, the second begins

Why and how to do this ?

Comment: If `Loop1Async` and `Loop2Async` would be actually asynchronous the code would produce results you expect... But since both are synchronous code simply runs normally.

Comment: @DStanley you probably mean some other method, not `Thread.Sleep`... Not everyone knows that `Task.Delay` is "sleep"...

Answer (score 6):

You have the fundamental misunderstanding common to beginner users of `await`.

Let me be very clear about this.  **Await does not make something asynchronous**.  It *asynchronously waits for an asynchronous operation to complete*.

You are awaiting a synchronous operation. There is absolutely nothing asynchronous about the methods you are calling; await does not make them asynchronous. Rather, if they *were* asynchronous, then the `await` would return control to the caller immediately, so that the caller could continue to do work.  When the asynchronous work finishes, then at some point in the future the remainder of the method is executed, with the `await`ed result.

Answer (score 1):

Try [`.WhenAll(...)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160374(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
static async Task MultiTasks()
{
    var Loop1 = Loop1Async();
    var Loop2 = Loop2Async();

    await Task.WhenAll(Loop1, Loop2);
}
```

As others have noted your `async` methods do not currently yield execution.

You need something that will allow threads to yield back to the system so they can actually run in parallel. Something like this...

```
static async Task Loop1Async()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Loop 1 : " + i);
        await Task.Yield();
    }
}

static async Task Loop2Async()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Loop 2 : " + i);
        await Task.Yield();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`Loop1Async` and `Loop2Async` in fact are synchronous. Consider using `WriteLineAsync` method.

You can also use `Task.WhenAll` in `MultiTasks`.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Loop1Async` and `Loop2Async` methods does not have an await inside. For a method to be `async` it needs to have 1 or more `await`